# Symfony2 and anonymous access to some route

Tags: php, symfony

With this configuration:

```
firewalls:
    login:
        pattern:  ^/login$
        anonymous:  ~
        security: false

    foo:
        pattern:   ^/foo$
        anonymous: ~
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /

access_control:
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/foo, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

I want to be able to make `/foo` anonymously accessible. However, when I try to go there even after clearing the cache it won't allow me to and redirects to login screen.

How do I make one route to be anonymously accessible while retaining the rest of the system to be secured?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Replace

```
- { path: ^/foo, roles: IS_ANONYMOUS }
```

with

```
- { path: ^/foo, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

**UPDATE**

Also, I believe, you will have to add

```
- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

for authentication to work properly.

For more info check out **Avoid Common Pitfalls** section [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#using-a-traditional-login-form).

Comment: Ok question update and I tried it, but it still redirects to login (I did clear the cache as well).

Comment: Okay looked liked it just did not work for `dev` environment for some reason.

Comment: @rFactor, it's hard to tell what's wrong now. Try to find clue in logs.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, my firewall won't allow anonymous on the one route in dev - the problem is we are only planning on using that route in dev. Did you figure out what was causing it?

Comment: @Jessica did you try to switch the order of the access_control rules?